# Android Studio Room: error when i get value from ArrayList

Tags: android

I have a database where I save an object, and inside it has an ArrayList of another object. It saves perfect, and I get them from the perfect database too. The problem is that if I print the session id (Sessions class) it prints it well (ex: Log.d("test", sessions.id)) but if I want to print the name of a product (within SessionProduct class) of that session (ex: Log.d("test",session.sessionProducts[0].name) it returns "NullPointer") The API returns well, I don't know if the problem is in how I save it, or in how I am setting it here:

```
@Entity
data class Sessions (
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("id") var id: String,
    @Embedded
    @SerializedName("items") var sessionProducts: ArrayList<SessionProduct>? = ArrayList() // El problema esta aca
) : Serializable
```

And sessionProducts:

```
@Entity
data class SessionProduct (
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id") var id: String,
    @SerializedName("name") var name: String
) : Serializable
```

(I Cutted the two classes so that it is not so extensive)

I used either a TypeConverter or not, and in both cases it throwed nullPointer too

```
@Database(entities = [Sessions::class, SessionProduct::class], version = 4, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(SessionsProductsConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase(){
```

I repeat: The problem is when I want to get what's inside ArrayList

```
@Dao
interface PendingSessionsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM sessions")
    fun getAllPendingSessions(): List<Sessions>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun addAllPendingSessions(sessions: List<Sessions>)

    @Update
    fun updatePendingSessions(sessions: List<Sessions>)

    @Query("DELETE FROM sessions")
    fun deleteAllTable()

}
```

This is the function where i save

```
fun addPendingSessions(context: Context, sessions: List<Sessions>){

        class AddPendingSessions : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {
                AppDatabase.getPendingSessionsDatabaseInstance(context).pendingSessionsDao().addAllPendingSessions(sessions)
                return null
            }

            override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
                super.onPostExecute(result)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Pending sessions saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }
        AddPendingSessions().execute()
    }
```

And for testing i do this:

```
Log.d("TestingPicking", sessionId.id) // This prints well on the console

for (product in sessionId.sessionProducts!!) // this throw NullPointer
    Log.d("TestingPicking", product.name) // this throw NullPointer
```

I tried everything I saw on the internet and I couldn't get it right. Maybe someone else has the same problem and knows how to fix it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try remove `@Embedded` of `sessionProducts` in the data class `Sessions`

**EDIT**

You need a type converter, see https://medium.com/@toddcookevt/android-room-storing-lists-of-objects-766cca57e3f9